# The WHERE clause function expects a tuple set expression for the argument. A string or numeric expression was used

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx, olap

I use SQL Server 2008 R2 and i use AdventureWorks2008 DataBase.

I Write MDX Query In SSAS.

I want filter result of query.

I write this query

```
SELECT 
Measures.[Internet Sales Amount] ON COLUMNS,
CROSSJOIN( 
            {Product.[Product Line].[Product Line].MEMBERS}, 
            {[Customer].[Country].MEMBERS}
         ) on ROWS 
FROM [Adventure Works] 
Where 
 ( Measures.[Internet Sales Amount] > 2000000 )
```

and i get this error

> Executing the query ...
>   The WHERE clause function expects a tuple set expression for the  argument. A string or >numeric expression was used.
>
> Execution complete

why i get this error?

Comment: What kind of database are you connecting to? What kind of language is this? i believe this is SSAS/MDX, isn't it?

Comment: i write that i use sql server 2008 r2 - and this is mdx query.

Comment: Well, if you want to draw attention of OLAP analysts, add MDX tag. I tried to retag your question but there were three geniuses that thought it was unnecessary...

Comment: You get this error because the filter(where clause) should be applied on a context like the aggregation on "Rows"

Comment: see? Just a little unnecessary tag...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this query

```
SELECT 
Measures.[Internet Sales Amount] ON COLUMNS,
Filter (
            CROSSJOIN( 
                        {Product.[Product Line].[Product Line].MEMBERS}, 
                        {[Customer].[Country].MEMBERS}
                     ) ,    
            ( Measures.[Internet Sales Amount] > 2000000 )       
         ) on ROWS 
FROM [Adventure Works]
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use what is recommended [here](http://www.dbforums.com/microsoft-sql-server/1206497-filter-measure-mdx.html).

Here is how your code should look like:

```
SELECT 
Measures.[Internet Sales Amount] ON COLUMNS,filter(
         ({Product.[Product Line].[Product Line].MEMBERS} *
            {[Customer].[Country].MEMBERS}),
            Measures.[Internet Sales Amount] > 2000000) on ROWS 
FROM [Adventure Works]
```